# How can i create a php conditial statement in drupal 7 page template

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-7

I wanted to render different regions on a page.tpl.php file based on the current pages title. The following code:

```
<?php if ($title == "My Drupal Page"): ?>
        <?php print $title; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

doesnt seem to work for me. i made sure to print the actual $title first and then copy pasted so it compares the correct title but still no results

Comment: use the `trim`..might sometime it issue with the space or something like that.

Comment: Suggestion: `Titles` meant to be ready by humans. For development comparison you should use `ID`s or kind of `slugs`. So instead of "About Us", the slug would be something like: `about-us`.

Comment: i was using taxonomy page, i did eventually make the switch to a node page so i could use node IDs. this is the first i've heard of slugs so i'll read into what they are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason this worked for me:

```
<?php if( drupal_get_path_alias() == "my-drupal-page"): ?>
  <?php print $title; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

i can only assume that there was extra text i couldn't see associated with $title.
drupal_get_path_alias() outputs the url alias and works as expected so far

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
    print t($title);
```

You might want to double check that your page title does indeed match 
"My Drupal Page"
Sometimes you need to define it as text for drupal to render correctly
Here's an example from one of my sites

```
    <?php if ($site_name): ?>
      <h1 class="site-name">
        <a href="<?php print $front_page; ?>" title="<?php print t('Home'); ?>" rel="home"><span><?php print $site_name; ?></span></a>
      </h1>
    <?php endif; ?>
```